# ER Diagram based on multiple databases & tables which derive names from column values from other table

Tags: mysql, relational-database, erd

So I have a Learning Management System. There are total 5 databases.

```
lms_data_db
lms_course_db
lms_test_db
..n two more
```

now whenever a row is added under `lms_data_db.course_data` say with `course_id=200`, a table named `course_200` is created under `lms_course_db`.

likewise when a row is added under `lms_course_db.course_100` with `chapter_id=100`, a table named `chapter_200_100` is created under `lms_test_db`.

My question is how to really put all that in an ERD!?

Comment: This sounds like something that is.. poorly thought through.

Comment: care to suggest an improvement then? anyways not like I care about an improvement right now.. as I have got too far now.. the thought was having separate tables for each course when one is created.. I suppose that was a good intention!

Comment: btw I know this much that ERDs don't need you to reflect the exact databases rather just to implement the entire Entity-Relationship right? so multiple db doesn't matter much right.. yet I am just confused about the naming thing

Comment: You should care about improvements right now because this structure is a maintenance _nightmare_. a separate table per course sounds fundamentally broken to me, as does putting all your tables into separate databases.  whats wrong with a single course table, a subject table, and then a relation table that joins the two together? course_subject ? that sort of thing

Comment: the course_data table stores { id,name,domain,shortDetail,pre-req,dateAdded,currentUserCount }.. now each of those course related tables containt {id, name, content, dateAdded}.. for each chapter there is one table that stores questions for generating a test & a table that stores which users r enrolled on the test & if finished their scores n detail.. now it's possible to put all of em on one database.. but won't it be more badly organized?!

Comment: no. you need to arrange this stuff relationally. it is an rdbms after all. it's hard to provide any further advice without knowing anything about your entities and how they relate to each other.  you just identifed at minimum a course table, user table, course_enrolment table, quiz table, quiz_questions table, user_questions table

Comment: Ok thanx for the advice pala_ I get your point.. actually I was more focused on how to handle the tables through mysql functions..  never gave much thought on whether or not to build a better database also because the entire project is fully functional & works just the way I wants it to.. Then again it's just a college project.. Not to be maintained further. But in future I will surely keep in mind to make relation tables rather than creating tons of separate db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deriving an ERD from an existing implementation is really reverse engineering.  You can look that term up for more reading.  If you agree that what you are doing is reverse engineering, then you should pay attention to the commentary provided by @pala_ on the design of the original db.

I suggest an entirely different approach, based on forward engineering.  Start with the subject matter.  Analyze the subject matter into entities and relationships between entities.  Discover attributes that describe these entities and relationships by means of data values.  These data values are what your database is going to store.

The above process yields an ER model and an ERD that depicts the subject matter, rather than a proposed solution.

Then you can proceed to designing a database that stores these data values in a way that makes sense, given the tools you are using and your intended use of the data.

Comment: thank you sir.. I am actually doing that.. I took the whole idea & ignored the exact db design.. rather implemented all the entities in the project & set up the relations between them.